# Vector storage in C++

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

I wish to store a large vector of d-dimensional points (d fixed and small: <10).

If I define a `Point` as `vector<int>`, I think a `vector<Point>` would store in each position a pointer to a Point.

But if define a `Point` as a fixed-size object like: 
`std::tuple<int,int,...,int>` or `std::array<int, d>`, 
will the program store all points in contiguous memory or will the additional level of indirection remain?

In case the answer is that arrays avoid the additional indirection, could this have a large impact on performance (cache exploit locality) while scanning the `vector<Point>`?

Comment: The standard vector class is supposed to be largely compatible with arrays, which means that the data it allocates is stored in a contiguous chunk of memory, just like an array. If you have a `std::vector<Point>` then all `Point` object would be stored contiguously. If the `Point` class have pointers itself (directly or indirectly (like when it has a vector)) then not all data will contiguously stored.

Comment: Yes, I would go the tuple route or better, just use a normal C-style struct (I still find tuple annoying to use, i.e. std::get<n>() is not really all that intuitive).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you define your `Point` as having contiguous data storage (e.g. `struct Point { int a; int b; int c; }` or using `std::array`), then `std::vector<Point>` will store the `Point`s in contiguous memory locations, so your memory layout will be:

```
p0.a, p0.b, p0.c, p1.a, p1.b, p1.c, ..., p(N-1).a, p(N-1).b, p(N-1).c
```

On the other hand, if you define `Point` as a `vector<int>`, then a `vector<Point>` has the layout of `vector<vector<int>>`, which is *not* contiguous, as `vector` stores *pointers* to dynamically allocated memory. So you have contiguity for *single* `Point`s, but not for the whole structure.

The first solution is much more efficient than the second (as modern CPUs love accessing contiguous memory locations).

Comment: Whether one is more efficient than the other depends on the use case. If you need to insert some data, then it may be much faster to just move around some pointers than copying all data.

Comment: In general, _measuring_ is a good thing. However, having cache-friendly structures tends to be great for performance; node-based structures tend to be bad for perf as they are cache unfriendly. Note that the cost of paging is high. Instead modern CPUs love accessing *contiguous* memory locations (that makes the prefetcher happy).

Answer (score 7):

`vector` will store whatever your type contains in contiguous memory. So yes, if that's an `array` or a `tuple`, or probably even better, a custom type, it will avoid indirection.

Performance-wise, as always, you have to measure it. Don't speculate. At least as far as scanning is concerned.

However, there will definitely be a huge performance gain when you create those points in the first place, because you'll avoid unnecessary memory allocations for every `vector` that stores a point. And memory allocations are usually very expensive in C++.

Answer (score 4):

For the said value of `d` (<10), defining `Point` as `vector<int>` will almost double the full memory usage by `std::vector<Point>` and will bring almost no advantage.

Answer (score 1):

As the dimension is fixed, I'd suggest you to go with a template which uses the dimension as a template param. Something like this:

```
template <typename R, std::size_t N> class ndpoint 
{
public:
  using elem_t=
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<R>::value, R>::type;

  static constexpr std::size_t DIM=N;

  ndpoint() = default;

  // e.g. for copying from a tuple
  template <typename... coordt> ndpoint(coordt... x) : elems_ {static_cast<R>(x)...} {
  }
  ndpoint(const ndpoint& other) : elems_() {
    *this=other;
  }

  template <typename PointType> ndpoint(const PointType& other) : elems_() {
    *this = other;
  }

  ndpoint& operator=(const ndpoint& other) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
      this->elems_[i]=other.elems_[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }

  // this will allow you to assign from any source which defines the
  // [](size_t i) operator
  template <typename PointT> ndpoint& operator=(const PointT& other) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<N; i++) {
      this->elems_[i]=static_cast<R>(other[i]);
    }
  }

  const R& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return this->elems_[i]; }

  R& operator[](std::size_t i) { return this->elems_[i]; }

private:
  R elems_[N];
};
```

Then use a `std::vector<ndpoint<...>>` for a collection of points for best performance.

Comment: How is this different/better compared to std::vector<std::array<>>?

Comment: "How is this better than std::vector<std::array<>>?" Control over the operations you can do to/with the ndpoint (e.g. add a `norm` method, or a `distanceTo`, etc). Performance-wise, it the same. Just don't use tuple or vector as storage for your nd-points.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be 100% sure how your data is structured is to fully implement own memory handling..

However, there are many libraries that implement matrices and matrix operations that you can check out. Some have documented information about contiguous memory, reshape etc. (e.g. OpenCV Mat).

Note that in general you can not trust that an **array** of Points will be contiguous. This is due to alignment, allocation block header etc. For example consider

```
struct Point {
   char x,y,z;
};

Point array_of_points[3];
```

Now if you try to 'reshape', that is, iterate between Point elements relaying on the fact that points are adjacent in the container - than it is most likely to fail:

```
(char *)(&array_of_points[0].z) != (char *)(&array_of_points[1].x)
```